# How to declare a variable with a variable name?

Tags: c#

How can I declare a variable inside a for loop

```
foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode xmlnode in node)
{
    string AMSListName = xmlnode.Attributes["Title"].Value.ToString();
    /* the below assignment should be variable for each iteration */
    XmlNode ndViewFields + AMSListName = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,
                                                           "ViewFields", "");
}
```

How do I achieve this? I want for each value in the for loop to have the xmlnode to have a different name. Is this possible at all?

Comment: Why? Perhaps a list with all of the nodes would be a better choice?

Comment: No, you cannot do this, unless perhaps with reflection. Use a collection to store your data in instead.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you want every variable to be named differently?

Comment: Can you describe the problem that you are trying to solve?  It looks like you are reading 1 xml file and outputting a new one with a different schema.  Is that right?

Comment: Even if this would work, how would you access these variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a collection:

```
List<XmlNode> nodes = new List<XmlNode>();
foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode xmlnode in node)
{
    string AMSListName = xmlnode.Attributes["Title"].Value.ToString();
    nodes.Add(xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", ""));
}
```

You can access this list via index or in a loop:

```
foreach(var node in nodes)
{
    // ...
}
```

another approach If the name is an identifier, use a `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<string, System.Xml.XmlNode> nodeNames = new Dictionary<string, System.Xml.XmlNode>();
foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode xmlnode in node)
{
    string AMSListName = xmlnode.Attributes["Title"].Value.ToString();
    nodeNames[AMSListName] = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "");
}
```

This will replace an already available node with a given name, otherwise it'll add it.

You can access it via name:

```
XmlNode node
if(nodeNames.TryGetValue("Some Name", out node)
{
    // ..
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using something like a dictionary or hastable.  Because even if you did create dynamic variables, how would you reference them later?  I am not sure this is possible.

```
            Hashtable ViewFields = new Hashtable();

        foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode xmlnode in node)
        {
            string AMSListName = xmlnode.Attributes["Title"].Value.ToString();
            XmlNode nd = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "");
            ViewFields.Add(AMSListName,nd);
        }
```